# My global var keeps re-defining itself

Tags: c, initialization, global

edit: solved. unsigned char fixed it.

I'm having problems with a home brew library that is supposed to psuedo-emulate vga 80x25 terminal so that I can work on some bad OS logic. Whenever I call `s_put_char`, it completely resets the flags char, and re-initializes my buffer.

My goal is for `s_init()` to be called only if `s_put_char` is called for the first time.

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

//this is so I can start coding logic without having to build a cross-compiler
//the only s_* method that should access by external code is s_put_char(char,int)

//all methods beginning with s_* are referring to the screen output
#define s_rows 25
#define s_columns 80
#define s_buffer_size 2000 //80x25 = 2000

char flags = 0;

//first bit is if the screen is inited or not.
char s_buffer[s_buffer_size]; //80x25

void s_update()
{
        system("cls");
        printf(s_buffer);
}

void s_init()
{
        int index = 0;
        while(index < s_buffer_size)
        {
                //s_buffer[index] = ' ';
                index++;
        }
        flags += 128; //flip first bit
        s_update;
}

void s_put_char(char c, unsigned int index)
{
        if(flags < 128){ s_init(); }
        //checks to see if the first bit is flipped or not.
        //if first bit not flipped, then screen needs to be inited
        s_buffer[index] = c;
        s_update();
}
```

My specs: Mingw + Msys, Win 8

Comment: Maybe, on your system, `char` is *signed*? If you want to do bit-checks use the bitwise operators, and *unsigned* data types.

Comment: `printf(s_buffer);
` This is not how we print a char array. Not a valid syntax.

Comment: That's not the complete code I think .

Comment: @ameyCU: What's not valid about it?

Comment: @JohnBode  Which one .`printf` ? I meant not valid to print a char array .Missing specifier.

Comment: @ameyCU: Don't need one to print a string.  `printf` expects a `const char *` as its first argument, so you can print a string argument with no conversion specifier.  Of course, if `s_buffer` doesn't contain a *string* (a 0-terminated sequence of printable characters), then we have problems.

Comment: @JohnBode  Seeing what his code does we can't say anything .And ofcourse I was also saying it was not valid to print a char array. We don't know it is string or not .

Answer (score 3):

In `s_init()`:

```
    s_update;
```

should be

```
    s_update();
```

shouldn't it?

Also – since `flags` is a signed char –

```
flags < 128
```

is always true.

Try defining `flags` as `unsigned char`.

EDIT:

Actually – as noted by @KeithThompson – `char` might behave either as signed or as unsigned depending on the implementation.

Comment: It absolutely should (the s_update; line).  As-is it is treated as a function pointer, and that line has no effect.

If you are going to do bit-wise manipulation on a variable like you are with flags, it is generally better to use bit-wise operators. That way you can avoid pit-falls like this one.

For example:
#define INIT_OFFSET 7
#define INIT_MASK     0x1 << INIT_OFFSET

if( (flags & INIT_MASK) != 0)
{
    foo();
}

Comment: `flags` is a `char`, not a `signed char`. They're distinct types, even if they (sometimes) have the same range and representation.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Correct. Actual type can be either signed or unsigned depending on the implementation.

Comment: Thanks! Adding unsigned char fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the compiler, `char` has the same range as one of `signed char` or `unsigned char`.  If your `char flags` is behaving like `signed char flags`, it will typically have a range of -128 to 127. So if it starts off with the value 0, adding 128 to it will overflow and become -128. So your `flags` variable is flipping between the values 0 and -128 each time your `s_init()` is called. Both of those values are less than 128, so `s_put_char()` always calls `s_init()`.

An `unsigned char` typically has a range of 0 to 255, so use that instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use explicit `flags ^= 0x80`, `(flags & 0x80) != 0` and `unsigned char`. As it stands, 128 is a sign bit in `char` and is interpreted as -128, so your `flags < 128` is always true, for 0 and for -128.